# Read in CSV in Pyspark with correct Datatypes

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I am trying to import a local CSV with spark, every column is by default read in as a string. However, my columns only include integers and a timestamp type. To be more specific, the CSV looks like this:

```
"Customer","TransDate","Quantity","PurchAmount","Cost","TransID","TransKey"
149332,"15.11.2005",1,199.95,107,127998739,100000
```

I have found code that should work in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926411/provide-schema-while-reading-csv-file-as-a-dataframe), but when I execute it all the entries are returned as `NULL`.

I use the following to create a custom schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType, TimestampType

customSchema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("Customer", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("TransDate", TimestampType, true),
        StructField("Quantity", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("Cost", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("TransKey", IntegerType, true)))
```

and then read in the CSV with:

```
myData = spark.read.load('myData.csv', format="csv", header="true", sep=',', schema=customSchema)
```

Which returns:

```
+--------+---------+--------+----+--------+
|Customer|TransDate|Quantity|Cost|Transkey|
+--------+---------+--------+----+--------+
|    null|     null|    null|null|    null|
+--------+---------+--------+----+--------+
```

Am I missing a crucial step? I suspect that the Date column is the root of the problem. Note: I am running this in GoogleCollab.

Comment: I'm surprised that the integers are being read incorrectly. Those dates definitely won't work because they're not in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format that's expected. I would recommend reading the csv using `inferSchema = True` (For example" `myData = spark.read.csv("myData.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)`) and then [manually converting the Timestamp fields from string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format).

Comment: Oh now I see the problem: you passed in `header="true"` instead of `header=True`. You need to pass it as a boolean, but you'll still get nulls for the timestamps because of the incorrect format.

Comment: What is wrong in? `header = "true"`

Comment: @Prazy though the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) is unclear, I am pretty sure that `header` should be one of `(False, True, None)` (boolean/None vs. string).

Comment: @pault header = "true" always works for me.

Comment: The accepted answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832312/how-to-make-the-first-first-row-as-header-when-reading-a-file-in-pyspark-and-con. Even, he used `header='true'`.

Comment: It could be a difference between `read.load` and `read.csv` but as I said, I have no documentation to back it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses. Indeed, if I use `inferSchema = True`, the integers are correctly formatted. This fixes my immediate problem, thanks! However, it would be great to do everything in one step by providing a custom schema. Is this also not possible by providing the input format of the stamp with something like `dd.MM.yyyy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go!

```
"Customer","TransDate","Quantity","PurchAmount","Cost","TransID","TransKey"
149332,"15.11.2005",1,199.95,107,127998739,100000
PATH_TO_FILE="file:///u/vikrant/LocalTestDateFile"
Loading above file to dataframe:
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferschema", "true") \
  .option("delimiter", ",").load(PATH_TO_FILE)
```

your date will get loaded as string column type, but the moment you change it to date type it will treat this date format as NULL.

```
df = (df.withColumn('TransDate',col('TransDate').cast('date'))

+--------+---------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
|Customer|TransDate|Quantity|PurchAmount|Cost|  TransID|TransKey|
+--------+---------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
|  149332|     null|       1|     199.95| 107|127998739|  100000|
+--------+---------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
```

So we need to change the date format from dd.mm.yy to yy-mm-dd.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

Python function to change the date format:

```
  change_dateformat_func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

call this function for your dataframe column now:

```
newdf = df.withColumn('TransDate', change_dateformat_func(col('TransDate')).cast(DateType()))

+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
|Customer| TransDate|Quantity|PurchAmount|Cost|  TransID|TransKey|
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
|  149332|2005-11-15|       1|     199.95| 107|127998739|  100000|
+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----+---------+--------+
```

and below is the Schema:

```
 |-- Customer: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- TransDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PurchAmount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Cost: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- TransID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- TransKey: integer (nullable = true)
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can specifiy an option `('dateFormat','d.M.y')` to the `DataFrameReader` to parse date in particular format.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("dateFormat","M.d.y").schema(my_schema).load("path_to_csv")
```

**Reference**

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/io.html