# Rename unnamed columns in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, databricks

The data is in excel file that means file format is in '.xlsx'. The Header for the table has been sort of split amongst the first two rows. How do I fix this? Are there any  solutions to take the best of the two names for each column, and make that column name as header

I have these rows in source file:

```
|Unnamed:_0|Unnamed:_1|Unnamed:_2|Unnamed:_3|Unnamed:_4|Year |2018|2018.1|
|Col1      |Col2      |Col3      |Col4      |Col5      |Month|Jul |Aug   |
```

I want to display header for the table as:

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Year_Month|2018_07|2018.1_08|
```

I would be glad if you would help me provide a solution for this since i am new to pyspark

Comment: what is the file format ? if csv , @Hubert Dudek answer is right option .

Comment: The file format is excel

Answer (score 0):

you can share more of your code but I bet that it header option for csv:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
```

if it is not csv you can use schema and specify column names in schema. Example with schema:

```
schema = StructType([
 StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
 StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
 StructField('lastname', StringType(), True),
 StructField('languages', ArrayType(StringType()), True),
 StructField('state', StringType(), True),
 StructField('gender', StringType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
```

sometimes also for csvs can be useful to auto detect schema from file so:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
```

if you load from excel you can also use above options like

```
.option("header", "true")
```

in loading excel useful is also option dataAddress as you can target table/selection as you do in excel so after some experiments header will match:

```
.option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet'!B3:C35")
```

if any of that solution is not working you can promote your first line to header but it is a bit complicated. An excellent script and manual how to do it by [@desertnaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685471/desertnaut) is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837299/10972959

Comment: This is for the case of csv file, i have data in .xlsx

Comment: can you share code to load excel so I could adjust it

Comment: Please check my question, i edited it with the code. Help me in that perspective

Comment: edited answer and added info about excel and also link to script which can be used to promote first line to header